# correct syntax for combining filters in mplayer-command

Tags: command-line, mplayer

I´m looking for the right way to combine filters in mplayer.

I want to achieve the following:

I´d like to play a .wav-file with the **equalizer**-option set and the **faster-speed**-option (plus: **not altering the pitch** when playing
faster).

Man-pages say:

> -af <filter1[=parameter1:parameter2:...],filter2,...>
>
> Setup a chain of audio filters.

Seems that´s what I´m looking for.

This command however doesn´t work:

```
mplayer -af scaletempo=scale=1.2:speed=pitch -srate 44100 -af lavcresample=44100 -af equalizer=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:7:7 test.wav
```

I.e.: the equalizer option does work (audio is much crisper) but it´s all played back at normal speed (not with the factor of "1.2").

Could anybody help me with the correct syntax?

Thanks a lot in advance.
Many greetings.
Rosika

P.S.:

my system is Linux/Lubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 0):

for those interested: with the help of some friendly and knowledgeable people from the **mplayer-mailing-list** I found the solution to the problem:

- Using the ***-af***-option commas have to be used for two or mor entries # OR:
- making use of the ***-af-add***-option.

These two commands work equally well:

- mplayer -af scaletempo=scale=1.2:speed=pitch,lavcresample=44100,equalizer=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:7:7 -srate 44100 test.wav
- mplayer -af scaletempo=scale=1.2:speed=pitch -srate 44100 -af-add lavcresample=44100 -af-add equalizer=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:7:7 test.wav

Many greetings.
Rosika